# Double Integral using Fubini's Theorem

Tags: integration

What is the best way to compute the follwing integral using Fubini's theorem?
$$
\int_{0}^{5}\int_{2x}^{10} y^4 e^{xy^2} dydx
$$

Answer (score 2):

Integrate over $x$ first, then $y$.  Be careful with the endpoints: it helps to draw a picture of the region you're integrating over.

Comment: But if I integrate over x first, in the end I'll have to validate $2x$ in terms of the integration in y... isn't that going to be a problem to my final result?

Comment: ...it helps to draw a picture of the region...